# Apache2 returning "APACHE_RUN_DIR" error on docker container

Tags: debian, docker

When trying to start my roundcube mailserver on a docker container I get the apache error:

```
AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_DIR} is not defined
apache2: Syntax error on line 80 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
DefaultRuntimeDir must be a valid directory, absolute or relative to 
ServerRoot
```

Even if I declared all the envvars in the dockerfile like:

```
#FROM armv7/armhf-debian
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install sudo -y
RUN sudo apt-get install nano

# install exim,d ovecot, fetchmail, roundcoube
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y exim4 sudo wget ca-certificates
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y dovecot-imapd
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y fetchmail procmail
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y apache2 php5.* php5.*-mysql

#add
RUN sudo mkdir -p /etc/php5/apache2/

# add www-data to sudoers
RUN echo "www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers

# removing std. html site
RUN sudo rm /var/www/html/index.html

# downloading roundcube
RUN wget https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/releases/download/1.2.3/roundcubemail-1.2.3-complete.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf roundcubemail-1.2.3-complete.tar.gz
RUN cp -rf roundcubemail-1.2.3/. /var/www/html/
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/
RUN echo "MAIN_TLS_ENABLE = 1" >> /etc/exim4/exim4.conf.localmacros

# setting date.timezone
RUN echo 'date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"' >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

# enable fetchmail as daemon
RUN echo "START_DAEMON=yes" >> /etc/default/fetchmail

# let dovecot listen on ipv6
RUN echo "listen = *" >> /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf

VOLUME ["/var/log/exim4"]

ADD ./scripts /scripts

# clean for smaller image
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# entrypoint
#ENTRYPOINT ["exim"]
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash /scripts/init.sh
#CMD [/scripts/init.sh]
```

I'm starting it with an init.sh file as seen below

I also checked if the evvars and direcories exist in the docker container.
The RUN_DIR is set and also /var/run/apache2 exists. Within is the apache2.pid set with an id.

When opening the localhost address the pure php code is shown..

Comment: What is in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` of the container. There seems to be an error on line 80.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor line 80 in debian `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is `DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}`. It seems the variables are not exported with `ENV APACHE_XXX yyy`.

Comment: @temp Why not use `service apache2 start`?

Comment: @Freddy How to export them?

adding `service apache2 start` at least let's me reach the port. But the problem's still there.

Comment: @temp Does it work if you export them in your `init.sh`, e.g. `export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/lock/apache2` (like in `/etc/apache2/envvars`)?

Comment: @Freddy i edited in the question what I just did. Like this it didn't work. Tried a bit more but still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove apache variables from docker file
- Replace `init.sh`:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  # define path to custom docker environment
  DOCKER_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/docker_envvars

  # write variables to DOCKER_ENVVARS
  cat << EOF > "$DOCKER_ENVVARS"
  export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
  export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
  export APACHE_LOG_DIR=/var/log/apache2
  export APACHE_LOCK_DIR=/var/lock/apache2
  export APACHE_PID_FILE=/var/run/apache2.pid
  export APACHE_RUN_DIR=/var/run/apache2
  EOF

  # source environment variables to get APACHE_PID_FILE
  . "$DOCKER_ENVVARS"

  # only delete pidfile if APACHE_PID_FILE is defined
  if [ -n "$APACHE_PID_FILE" ]; then
     rm -f "$APACHE_PID_FILE"
  fi

  # start other services
  service exim4 start
  service dovecot start
  service fetchmail start

  # line copied from /etc/init.d/apache2
  ENV="env -i LANG=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

  # use apache2ctl instead of /usr/sbin/apache2
  $ENV APACHE_ENVVARS="$DOCKER_ENVVARS" apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND
  ```

Comment: I used your init and removed the stuff from my dockerfile (see edited question).. but still the same error. :/

Comment: @temp It works on my debian. The important change is to define `APACHE_ENVVARS` and to use `apache2ctl`. Apache should start in foreground if you run `APACHE_ENVVARS=/etc/apache2/docker_envvars apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND` in terminal as root.

Comment: Okay... Any idea what the problem in my case could be?
Maybe something with the docker setup?